# Group questions and answers for each participant using R

Tags: r, group-by

I have a survey datasheet for a group of participants and each participant has a unique ID. But all of the questions and answers were listed as individual rows for each participant, for example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGdmM.png)

I would like to clean up the data and add each question as an individual column with one participant correspond to one row with all questions and answers using R like below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRS5M.png)

I assume there is something using the "group_by()" function, but I am not sure how exactly should I do it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a library or a function so I write it down below.

There should exist a function but I can't remember it.

Anyway the code below work fine even if "lack pattern".

```
d<-data.frame(rep(1:3,each=5), strsplit(strrep("ABCDE",3),""), 1:15)
colnames(d)<-c("Enrollment_ID","Question","Answer")
d
#      Enrollment_ID Question Answer
#  1         1           A       1
#  2         1           B       2
#  3         1           C       3
#  :         :           :       :

tbl <- function(d){
    d<-d[order(d[,1], d[,2]), ]        # sort dataframe
    res<-c()                           # vector for result
    rh<-sort(unique(d$Enrollment_ID))  # row header
    ch<-sort(unique(d$Question))       # col header
    for(r in rh){
        for(c in ch){
            v<-d[d[,1] == r & d[,2] == c, 3]
            res<-c(res, ifelse(length(v)==0, "", v))
        }        # replace unmatched value to empty string
    }
    return(matrix(res, ncol=length(ch), byrow=T, dimnames=list(rh, ch)))
}

tbl(d)
#     A  B  C  D  E
#  1  1  2  3  4  5
#  2  6  7  8  9 10
#  3 11 12 13 14 15

# even if we remove the first record of d, tbl func works fine

tbl(d[-1,])
#     A    B    C    D    E   
#  1   ""  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5" 
#  2  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9" "10"
#  3 "11" "12" "13" "14" "15"
```

Answer (score 0):

That's precisely the kind of transformation task that `pivot_wider` is best for:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Question,
              values_from = Answer,
              names_glue = "Question_{.name}")
# A tibble: 3 × 5
     ID Question_A Question_B Question_C Question_D
  <dbl> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     
1     1 xxx        xxx        xxx        xxx       
2     2 xxx        xxx        xxx        xxx       
3     3 xxx        xxx        xxx        xxx
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
  Question = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D"),
  Answer = c(rep("xxx", 12))
)
```